# How to do to perform post request with http/2 pipelining

Tags: linux, https, bash-scripting, pipelining, http-2

As part of a bash script, I need to send a huge number (between 90,000 and 100,000) of json post requests over the same connection to a server which supports http/2 and pipelining

Which is the command I need to use for that?

Comment: netcat looks like it's the tool to use. See if you can extend this approach: https://superuser.com/questions/603031/testing-http-pipeline-with-nc-but-got-only-one-response

Comment: @GregHNZ http/2 is a binary protocol and it s pipelining is deferent from 1.1. A program is required in order to handle it.